# Find Out If A Post With Specific Meta Value Exists?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been working on a plugin which involves custom post types. Each post of this type has a 'time' meta key that I create with the post by using wp_insert_post and add_post_meta:

```
foreach ($place->result->reviews as $review) {

    //first check if the post exists using the meta data
    $query_meta = array(
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'meta_query' => [
            'meta_key' => 'time',
            'meta_value' => "$review->time"]
    );

    $time_posts = new WP_Query($query_meta);

    if ($time_posts->post_count == 0) {

        //iterate the reviews module into the Total Testimonials Custom Post Type
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_type' => 'testimonials',
            'post_title' => 'Review ' . $review->time,
            'post_content' => $review->text,
            'post_excerpt' => $review->text,
            'post_thumbnail' => $review->profile_photo_url,
            'post_author' => $review->author_name,
            'post_status' => 'draft',
            'comment_status' => 'closed', // if you prefer
            'ping_status' => 'closed', // if you prefer
        ));


        add_post_meta($post_id, 'time', "$review->time");
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'post_rating', $review->rating);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'testimonial_author', $review->author_name);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'thumbnail', $review->profile_photo_url);
    }
}
```

Each time the plugin executes (its on a wp-cron event) its supposed to pull down any new testimonials from the source, and then parse them one by one via a loop checking to see if a post with the same time exists, if it does then no insertion should occur - if it doesnt, then the new testimonial should be inserted in the manner above.

I have tried checking for the presence of the existing posts in 3 ways:

```
$query_meta = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'time',
                'value' => $review->time,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
        )
    );

    $post = query_posts($query_meta);

    if (count($post) == 0) // insert
```

I have also tried this method:

```
    $posts = get_posts(['meta_key' => 'time', 'meta_value' => $review->time]);

     if (count($posts) == 0) // insert
```

And finally this way:

```
$query_meta = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'time',
                'value' => $review->time,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
        )
    );

    $post = new WP_Query($query_meta);

    if ($post->have_posts() == FALSE) //insert
```

With each of these attempts I end up with duplicated posts for the custom post type. Can someone show me what Im doing wrong here? Checking to see if a post exists shouldnt be this difficult in my opinion. So I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Your Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trying everything I could think of - I ended up going with a direct SQL query through wpdb. This seems to be the only way I could effectively determine if the post with the custom meta data existed:

```
$hasdata = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key='time' and meta_value='$review->time'");

if (count($hasdata) == 0) {
      //insert data
```

Comment: man, this line returns an error....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll want to set the WP_Query object with the $post var since it's native to WP. I had luck with the following:

```
$query_meta = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonials',
    'meta_key' => 'time',
    'meta_value' => $review->time
);
$time_posts = new WP_Query( $query_meta );

if ( $time_posts->post_count == 0 ) {
    echo 'insert things';
}
```

Comment: Hi Epierpont - I tried your solution but still have the same duplication issue occurring everytime the cron executes.

Comment: Not sure. Maybe the cron is executing twice?